# New transition object created on redirect

Tags: ember.js

I have some Ember code in a route where I am waiting on a transition object in order to act after the transition completes:

```
willTransition: function (transition) {
    ...

    // Wait until the transition has finished before continuing.
    transition.then(function () {
        // Transition successful
        ...
    }, function () {
        // Transition aborted
        ...
    });
}
```

The "successful transition" function is called in all but one case in my app. This case is when the transition is to a route which performs a transitionTo in its redirect method. The call to transitionTo aborts the original transition - the one I'm waiting on in my code above - and replaces the active transition with a new one. The promise I'm waiting on is then rejected so my abort handler is called.

Is there any way I can get the new transition object and wait on that?

Answer (score 1):

As of Ember 1.2 ([changelog here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#ember-120-november-22-2013)) the `didTransition` hook was added to the router ([pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/3453)).

`didTransition` will be called after the transition has occurred.

```
App.TestRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    willTransition: function(transition) {
      ...
    },
    didTransition: function() {
      ...
    }
  }
});
```

[JSBin example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uCAHUWog/1/edit)

Comment: This is a nice addition, but doesn't quite seem to fit what I want to do: I'm using the currentPath property of the application controller to grab help content based on where the user currently is in the app, but that doesn't seem to have been updated by the time didTransition is called.

Now I think about it, perhaps simply observing currentPath for changes would suffice...

Comment: What about using `this.router.get('url')` from `didTransition` or `setupController`?

Comment: Nice suggestion - I've never actually looked at using properties from the router as I've always felt it's something "internal". The issue is that this returns the URL, when it's the current Ember route name I'm after since it's easier to handle dynamic segments that way.